# Is there a good gem like 'Add Media' function in Wordpress?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Allowing users to upload images and add them to an WYSIWYG editor is always a headache to me.
Recently I found out that Wordpress' 'Add Media' function is very convenient.
(http://en.support.wordpress.com/add-media/)

Is there a Rails gem like that?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have not used this yet, but this is where I would start: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

I use the editor itself for letting users create rich content and if you could tie in the ability to add in images, it would be pretty sweet.  The docs make it look like you can...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've been using TinyMCE and it's very similar to CKEditor. What impressed me when I used wordpress was that you can drag&drop multiple images to upload and you can easily select image to insert to the editor.